# Added new entity to model - although it doesnt show up in generated code

Tags: entity-framework

I have added a new entity to our edmx. We have the ..dataaccess.g.cs file that is generated. This generated file does not seem to show the new entity I created, even when I delete it and rebuild our Entity project. I need this because it is a navigation property that we need to be able to access. any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: accepting answers to some of your previous questions would *also* be appreciated, which is why this question has been open for 8 hours and no-one is willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing some needed namespaces in a partial classes that we created off this domain service

Comment: The concept of 'closed' is different from that of 'answered' - if you found a solution, then please post an answer here, for the benefit of others who might have the same problem. You should also *accept* some of the answers to your previous questions by using the green checkmark on the left side of answers that have helped solve your problem, to show gratitude to the answerers and to mark the question as 'solved'.